# Node Js en mi servidor

Tags: php, nodejs, apache, servidor, socket.io

Quiero montar en mi servidor (cpnel  no es compartido) un pequeño sistema de notificaciones en real time y voy a utilizar `node js` con `socket.io`, **mi pregunta es que requisitos debo tener en mi servidor o que debo habilitar para que funcione**, lo que si tengo claro es que no debe ser un servidor compartido.

no se si esta terminal de mi servidor me sirva para montar o instalar node js

[image: me da la opcion de abrir terminal]

[image: esta es la terminal]

No soy experto en servidores gracias

Comment: si es una terminal de linux prueba logearte como root e instalar node, para empezar...

Comment: Por casualidad mi estimado, ¿has visto la documentación?

Answer (score 1):

Los permisos de la terminal de cpanel son muy reducidos.
no creo que de deje instalar aplicaciones ni siquiera en el entorno del usuario. 
(seria un caos para el administrador del servidor)

Si node js esta instalado en el servidor al teclear `node` deberías ver el interprete >

También puede probar a poner `node -v` 
Deberías ver la versión de node que tienes instalado.

[image: Terminal comandos desde cpanel.]

En mi caso(desde mi Cpanel) no esta instalado y no lo puedo instalar.

Sin embargo (para que puedas comparar) con otro tipo de servicio. (ej una VPS OpenVz).
Si que te dejaría.

[image: Terminal vps]

En el caso de que te dejaría. (veo que tu cpanel no es compartido.)
deberías ejecutar `uname -a` o `cat /etc/*-release` 
para saber que sistema operativo tienes.

y luego en función del sistema operativo (debian, redhat, centos,...).
tienes que ejecutar un comando diferente para instalar nodejs.